# Join query for 2 tables

Tags: sql, join

I have 2 tables naming `port` and `rate`.

```
Port has (id, country, name) 
rate has (id, description, rate_min, rate_max, Origin_id, Destination_id).
```

I need to create a query to display `rate id, origin port name, destination port name, rate_min and rate_max` for all the `ports`. Give alias name for origin port name as `'source_port'` and destination port name as `'dest_port'`

Can anyone help me with the query for the above scenario?

Comment: I would like to help you but can you include your query?

Comment: It would be nice to include the create table scripts for the tables

Comment: Welcome to S/O.  Please note that when posting a question, you should always post some example of data source(s) and expected output.  Also, show what YOU have attempted vs just "I need the answer".  Also, when people comment with questions, edit your original post to add details or clarification as needed.  George's answer should get you what you need though.

Answer (score 0):

what are you loking for is a simple join between the rate and port table-> once for getting the origin_name and once for destination_name. Assuming that origin_id and destination_id are foreign keys to the port table.

```
create table port(id int, country varchar(50), name varchar(50));
create table rate(id int, description varchar(50), rate_min int, rate_max int, Origin_id int, Destination_id int);


select a.rate id
      ,b.id as origin port name
      ,c.id as destination port name
      ,a.rate_min
      ,a.rate_max 
  from rate a
  join port b 
    on a.origin_id=b.id
  join port c
    on a.destination_id=c.id
```

Comment: . . You should learn to use meaningful table aliases so technically correct answers can be upvoted.

Comment: Will do.  In this example how would you alias?

Comment: Thanks will do. Please spell my name properly :)